# How can I import a file present in different folder in python?

Tags: python-3.x, import

I have the following structures:

- SnapQuick

  - main

    - snap_view.py
    - login.py
    - signup.py
  - profile

    - profile.py

profile.py has the following imports

```
from os import sys
sys.path.insert(1,'../')

from main import login
import sqlite3

class profile():
    def show_profile(self,user_id):
        pass(some_code....)
```

login.py has the following imports

```
import sqlite3
from os import sys,system

sys.path.insert(1,"../")

import signup
from profile import profile
import snap_main


class login:
    def login(self):
```

On running profile.py I am getting an error

**Error:**

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "profile.py", line 6, in
>   
>       from main import login   File "../main/login.py", line 6, in 
>       import signup ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'signup'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(".../SnapQuick/profile") (you need whole path)
from profile import login
```